# Static and Dynamic value to Column Name in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Check the following table:

```
--------------------------------
ID    Value    GroupName
--------------------------------
1     10       A
2     12       B
3     19       A
4     5        B
5     9        A
6     12       B
7     17       C
8     21       C
9     8        C
10    15       A
--------------------------------
```

I want to have the following output:

```
-------------------------
A     B      C
-------------------------
10    12     17
19    5      21
9     12     8
15    NULL   NULL
-------------------------
```

So, all values in `'GroupName'` field will become a new column.
Does anyone know how to do this in SQL 2008?

Thank you.

Comment: How about you search for pivot and give it a try?

Comment: @Mihai answer it and I'll vote it up

Comment: `SELECT (CASE WHEN GroupName='A' THEN Value END) A,(CASE WHEN GroupName='B' THEN Value END) B,(CASE WHEN GroupName='C' THEN Value END) C FROM table`

Comment: @Mihai, How if I don't know what is the next value in 'GroupName' field?

Comment: I think you can do it with dynamic sql but this is beyond my knowledge look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: @Mihai, thank you. That's very good link. Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using `PIVOT`; and the given below example is for only 3 static values `A, B and C`:

```
select [A], [B], [C] From(
    select 
        Value, GroupName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GroupName order by GroupName) RN
    From 
        tbl
)up pivot (sum(value) for GroupName in ([A], [B], [C]))x
```

For dynamic values,

```
DECLARE @pivv NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @pivv=COALESCE(@pivv+',','')+ QUOTENAME(GroupName) 
from tbl group by GroupName

IF ISNULL(@pivv, '')<>''
set @Query=
    'select '+@pivv+' From(
        select 
            Value, GroupName, 
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GroupName order by GroupName) RN
        From 
            tbl
    )up pivot (sum(value) for GroupName in ('+@pivv+'))x'

exec (@Query)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/849f2/1)

Comment: If you don't mind. Would you please complete the answer? Dynamic values? Thank you.

Comment: For dynamic values, It has to be done in Storeprocedure, right? Or possible just run in view?

Comment: Yes, you can go for a stored procedure. View wont work I guess.

Comment: Okay. One more thing, Is it possible to make an alias for each column? ColumnName as myColumn, something like that.